# Sleep in case of error, python

Tags: python, error-handling, exception

So I have a situation where I am to use internet connection for 12 hours straight and make calls to an api. But Light keeps going off after every 10 minutes. Is is possible to write a try, except function that will cause a delay of 10 minutes in case an error of timed out is generated. It is hopeful that the electricity will come back in 10 minutes.|
This is what I am currently using:

```
try:
        a=translator.translate(str(x1),dest='hi')   
        b=translator.translate(str(x2),dest='hi')
    except:
        sleep(60*10)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `retry` module for these kind of retrying on exception. This makes the code to look much cleaner. `pip install retry` should install the module

```
from retry import retry

@retry(Exception, delay=10*60, tries=-1)
def my_code_that_needs_to_be_retried_for_ever():
    a=translator.translate(str(x1),dest='hi')   
    b=translator.translate(str(x2),dest='hi')

# Call the function
my_code_that_needs_to_be_retried_for_ever()
```

With the above code, when `my_code_that_needs_to_be_retried_for_ever` is invoked it would be retried every 60*10 seconds (10 mins) forever  (as tries is set to -1) everytime the code inside the fuction block raises an Exception

Answer (score 2):

Use `try` and `except` to catch the exception and then [`time.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/time.html#time.sleep) to make your Python script sleep for the desired amount of time. You can then put everything inside an endless `while` loop and `break` out of it once everything finished.

```
while True:
    try:
        # put everything here which might produce exception
        pass 
        # if this point is reached everything worked fine, so exit loop
        break
    except:
        time.sleep(10*60)
```

You can run the following example to see the general idea:

```
import random
import time

print("Before loop")

while True:
    try:
        print("Try to execute commands")
        # your commands here
        if random.random() > 0.3:
            print("Randomly simulate timeout")
            raise Exception("Timeout")
        print("Everything done")
        break
    except:
        print("Timeout: sleep for 2 seconds and try again")
        time.sleep(2)

print("After loop")
```

Instead of real commands, we randomly decide to raise an exception to simulate the timeout. The result might look something like this:

```
Before loop
Try to execute commands
Randomly simulate timeout
Timeout: sleep for 2 seconds and try again
Try to execute commands
Randomly simulate timeout
Timeout: sleep for 2 seconds and try again
Try to execute commands
Randomly simulate timeout
Timeout: sleep for 2 seconds and try again
Try to execute commands
Everything done
After loop
```